# NodeJs how to pass variable into export function

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I have NodeJs restful api made by tutorial. And in my endpoint I want to pass export function. For example:

```
// main.js
REST_ROUTER.prototype.handleRoutes = function(router, connection, md5) {
    router.get("/create", function(req, res) {
        var query = ... 
        connection.query(query,function(err, row) {...}
    });
}
```

But I want to do it like this:

```
// main.js
var example = require('./example.js');

REST_ROUTER.prototype.handleRoutes = function(router, connection, md5) {
    router.get("/create", example.create);
}

// example.js
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    var query = ... 
    connection.query(query,function(err, row) {...}
}
```

However, my `connection` is not available in example.js. How can I pass it?

Comment: `exports.connection.<stuff>`...?

Comment: @Cerbrus can you explain pls?

Comment: Just a guess. Don't mind me 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this might help:

```
// main.js
var example = require('./example.js');

REST_ROUTER.prototype.handleRoutes = function(router, connection, md5) {
    router.get("/create", example.create(connection));
}

// example.js
exports.create = function(connection) {
    return function(req, res) {
       var query = ... 
       connection.query(query,function(err, row) {...}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind example to create `example.create.bind(example,connections)`

```
// main.js
var example = require('./example.js');

REST_ROUTER.prototype.handleRoutes = function(router, connection, md5) {
    router.get("/create", example.create.bind(example,connections));
}

// example.js
exports.create = function(connection, req, res) {
    var query = ... 
    connection.query(query,function(err, row) {...}
}
```